# Вопрос по верстке блока

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дошел до вот такого блока в макете. Смущает то что уж как то слишком пиксель в пиксель блок наезжает на всю длину паддингов колонок. Это ошибка дизайнера макета(опять-__-)? На каком то из уроков по бутстрапу который я смотрел слышал что если блок наезжает на паддинг то по любому к длине этого блока добавляется одна колонка(в макете это происходит с обеих сторон и по этой идее блок должен занимать 11 колонок, контент-карточка должна иметь заданный max-width и выравниваться по центру блока). Но возникает вопрос нормально ли это вообще делать на сетке?Разве не пропадает тогда вся суть удобства сетки то есть дать верстальщику возможность удобно позиционировать и задавать размеры элемента? В любом случае как поступить? Укоротить блок до 9 колонок или делать 11? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Не задавайте блоку вобще сетку.
Поместите в контейнер (грубо говоря по сетке будет 12) и внутри уже создайте свои дивы с нужными вам размерами.

Comment: @Nilsan но с сеткой то удобнее)

Comment: а если можно офтоп __не используйте вообще bootstrap

Comment: @НикитаФаст я не использую bootstrap я использую сетку)

Comment: а для чего у вас тогда стоит тег `bootstrap` ?

Comment: Вообще тема сеток для меня самый сложный вопрос в освоении. Но я верю что если пойму их то обрету силу)

Comment: вы просто css изучите и тогда сетка любого размера будет вам понятна , а bootstrap это явно лишнее ...достаточно увидеть их медиазапросы и делать ...больше ни чего не надо

Comment: @НикитаФаст ну сетка то 12 колонок бутстраповская но это не значит то что это его фишка, я и сам могу написать сетку. Просто я думал что когда говорят не используй бутстрап подразумевают не не использование сеток как таковых а всю остальную часть его классов .

Comment: @midia не совсем понимаю чем с сеткой удобней :-) вот в вашем примере как раз и хорошо показано что с сеткой не удобно. 
Данный макет не вижу смысла вобще привязывать к сетке. Только головную боль наживёте себе :-)

Comment: @Nilsan А когда сетку тогда уместно  использовать?